# ERROR: 'Unhandled Promise rejection: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Getting this error when run ng test.

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')

```
  this.slotSvc.getFiscalWeek(startDate, 1)
      .then(function (data) {
          const inductionYear = (data[0].id).split('-')[1];
          const shopId = slot.shop.id;
          const ohLines = [];
          this.slotSvc.getOlLinesForShop(shopId, inductionYear)
              .subscribe(function (d) {
                  _.each(d, function (dataOL) {
                      let slotLineType;
                      if (slot.linetype) {
                          slotLineType = slot.linetype;
                      } else {
                          slotLineType = slot.assignedAssetInfo.lineTypes[0];
                      }
                      if (dataOL.lineTypes[0] === slotLineType && dataOL.name.includes(slot.assetType)) {
                          const olJson = { 'id': dataOL.id, 'displayName': dataOL.displayName };
                          ohLines.push(olJson);
                      }
                  }.bind(this));
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are accessing id props from data that does not exists. Try to monitor data params and log data if it contains id prop or not.

Comment: just to add to the above answer: either 1. data is undefined for data[0].id   2. shop is undefined at slot.shop.id  or 3.  dataOL is undefined at dataOL.id   - - agree with Awais: set a breakpoint at each of the three places above to find out which one(s) is/are undefined.

Comment: I added breakpoints and also did a console log for data and id, I could see the data available.  
>data[0].id
 'FW47-2021'

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this const inductionYear = (data[0]?.id).split('-')[1];

after putting question mark it will not give any undefined error.

Comment: Your answer does not quite solve the problem presented. It will suppress the first point of error but it fail again later. Specifically `(data[0]?.id)` will produce the value of `undefined` if `data[0]` is undefined. Then JS will try to do the `split()` on the `undefined` which will break it again. You can add another question mark to suppress that error. Then later on the code that depends on `inductionYear` will break because it's `undefined`. You can probably see where this is going. The correct way of handling is not to suppress the errors but to find the root of the problem and handle it.